# Google translate widget is showing on webpage with a delay

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have added Google Translate Widget in the navigation bar of my website. However, all the rest of the navigation options are displayed on the page load except for the translation option. It is displayed with a delay. How can I make it appear at the same time as that of the other navigation bar options?

```js
 <script>
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'en,zh-CN,zh-TW', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#google_translate_element').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
      $('.goog-te-menu-value span:first').html('Language');
      $('.goog-te-menu-frame.skiptranslate').load(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('.goog-te-menu-frame.skiptranslate').contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item-selected .text').html('Translate');    
        }, 10);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
  <script>     
$('document').ready(function () {

  // RESTYLE THE DROPDOWN MENU
    $('#google_translate_element').on("click", function () {

        // Change font family and color
        $("iframe").contents().find(".goog-te-menu2-item div, .goog-te-menu2-item:link div, .goog-te-menu2-item:visited div, .goog-te-menu2-item:active div, .goog-te-menu2 *")
            .css({
                'color': '#fff',
       'background-color': '#0069BD',
                'font-family': 'Helvetica',
     'font-size': '17px',


            });
        // Change menu's padding
        $("iframe").contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item-selected').css ('display', 'none');
   
    // Change menu's padding
        $("iframe").contents().find('.goog-te-menu2').css ('padding', '0px 0px 0px 0px');
      
        // Change the padding of the languages
        $("iframe").contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item div').css('padding', '12px 16px ');
      
        // Change the width of the languages
        $("iframe").contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item').css('width', '100%');
        $("iframe").contents().find('td').css('width', '100%');
      
        // Change hover effects
        $("iframe").contents().find(".goog-te-menu2-item div").hover(function () {
            $(this).css('border-bottom', '3px solid  #00A0EF').find('span.text').css('color', 'white');
        }, function () {
            $(this).css('border-bottom', 'red').find('span.text').css('color', 'white');
        });
        // Change Google's default blue border
        $("iframe").contents().find('.goog-te-menu2').css('border', 'none');

    
        // Change the iframe's size and position?
        $(".goog-te-menu-frame").css({
            'height': '91px',
            'width': '185px',
            'top': '86px',
   '-webkit-box-shadow' : 'none', 
   '-moz-box-shadow' : 'none', 
   'box-shadow' : 'none',
   'text-align' : 'left',
   'z-index': '1000',
   'background-color': '#0069BD'
   
        });
  
    $(".goog-te-banner-frame").css({
       
   'z-index': '1000'
   
        });
  
        // Change iframes's size
        $("iframe").contents().find('.goog-te-menu2').css({
            'height': '100%',
            'width': '100%',
   'background-color': '#0069BD'
  
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

```css
/* Navigation Bar */
.navbar {
   width: 90;
 
   text-align: center;
   height: 20px;
   padding: 35px;
   font-size: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
    
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
 color: #0069BD;
 font-family: Helvetica;
}
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 20px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    margin: 0;
 color: #0069BD;
 background: transparent;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
     border-bottom: 3px solid  #00A0EF;

}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #0069BD;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1000;
 font-size: 10px;
  
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
 font-size: 17px; 
 
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
 border-bottom: 3px solid  #00A0EF;
 color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
         <a  href="Marvel_Tech.html">Home</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn">Services 
       <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="Services.html">Software</a>
    <a href="#">Consulting</a>
    <a href="#">Design</a>
  </div>
   </div> 
    <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn">Products 
       <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> <! dropdown menu arrow>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="Services.html">Software</a>
    <a href="#">Consulting</a>
    <a href="#">Design</a>
  </div>
   </div> 

  <div class="dropdown">
      <div id="google_translate_element"></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where you are calling the script at top or bottom?

Comment: @RopAliMunshi previously it was at the bottom, after your comment I have moved it to head section. it is now appearing at a much faster rate, but still, it has a delay of seconds. Because of the delay, when the language option appears it feels as navigation bar is moving from right to left.

Comment: I am actually not able to visualize your problem. I think some delayed is justified because it also depends on your Internet connection speed.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi thank you. and yes I also think the delay is linked to the internet speed. However, in the case of slow networks, this will still be a persisting problem.